# Is it possible to use an array value as a switch case value?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to create a working Java code. I created an encryption function that takes any symbol in a string and replaces it with a value from an array.

The problem is very simple. Decryption function must take any value written in an array and use it to decrypt. The code describes it better than I do.

```
   case "1" -> output += n_encryptions[0];
// Then in decrypt():
   case n_encryptions[0] -> output += "1";
// Sadly, this creates an error
```

My goal is to make an easily changeable encryption and decryption system, since I am planning to change these values in the future.

I need a way to use an array value (n_encryptions[0] in the example) as a case parameter.

Edit: I guess an if statement is the best option. Thanks!

Comment: Use a normal if else combination instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use an array value as a switch case value?

No, it is not.

Switch labels (to the right of the word **case**) must be compile-time constant expressions.

> I need a way to use an array value (n_encryptions[0] in the example)
> as a case parameter.

Why do you 'need' this?  It surely can be expressed another way,for example by using **if**.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you problem, a usual approach to this is to have 2 arrays

```
char[] from = {'a','b','c'};
char[] to = {'1','e','@'};
```

Read your input char by char, look up the position of the char in `from` and replace it with the char from the same position in `to`.

Reverse, the same (to -> from).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just suggesting a way of solving the problem. You can use a `Map<Character, Character>` for encryption and another for decryption. You can adapt the following program to your needs.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Character> encryptionMap = new HashMap<>();
        encryptionMap.put('a', '-');
        encryptionMap.put('b', '+');
        encryptionMap.put('-', '1');
        encryptionMap.put('+', '3');
        
        String plainText = "a+b-a";
        String encryptedText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
            char ch = plainText.charAt(i);
            encryptedText += encryptionMap.get(ch);
        }
        System.out.println("Plain Text: " + plainText);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + encryptedText);

        Map<Character, Character> decryptionMap = new HashMap<>();
        decryptionMap.put('-', 'a');
        decryptionMap.put('+', 'b');
        decryptionMap.put('1', '-');
        decryptionMap.put('3', '+');

        String decryptedText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedText.length(); i++) {
            char ch = encryptedText.charAt(i);
            decryptedText += decryptionMap.get(ch);
        }
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText);
    }
}
```